# SQL MAX() grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Tables:**

```
student(sid, sname, sex, age, year, gpa)

major(dname, sid)
```

Question: 
For each department with more than 15 students majoring in the department, we want to print information about the student(s) with the highest GPA within the department.  In particular, for each such student, we want to print the student id, student name and GPA, and the department name the student is major in.

So far I have:

```
SELECT student.sid, student.sname, student.gpa, major.dname
FROM student 
RIGHT JOIN major ON student.sid = major.sid 
WHERE student.gpa IN (
    SELECT  MAX(gpa) 
    FROM student JOIN major ON student.sid = major.sid
    GROUP BY dname
    HAVING COUNT(dname) > 15
)
```

But it doesn't give me the accurate query. The clause inside the IN works but when put together in this way it doesn't actually match `student.gpa` to `dname` max GPA. What am I doing wrong here?

This Query gives:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yetFF.png)

I need:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0OSL.png)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Can you post sample data, the results you are getting and expected results?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name based on his history and nick, probably ms sql server.

Comment: Alias your inner query `student` table. It is most likely trying to join to the outer student table as well. Alias all of your tables for easier reading and debugging.

Comment: I'm using sql-server.

Comment: Please put any sample data in as formatted text, *not* images as they make the question hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query gives you the maximum GPA for each department. Then the outer query returns all students who have a GPA equal to **any** of the maximum GPA's, regardless of the department. The quickest fix of your code is to use a correlated subquery, that will find the maximum GPA for the student's specific department.

```
SELECT s.sid, s.sname, s.gpa, sm.dname
FROM student s
RIGHT JOIN major sm ON s.sid = sm.sid 
WHERE student.gpa IN (
   SELECT  MAX(ds.gpa) 
   FROM student ds JOIN major dm ON ds.sid=dm.sid
   WHERE dm.dname = sm.dname
   GROUP BY dm.dname
   HAVING COUNT(dm.dname)>15
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select dname, max(s.gpa) maxgpa
from major m inner join student s
on s.sid = m.sid
group by dname
having count(s.sid) > 15
```

returns all the departments with more than 15 students and the highest gpa in that department.
Join it to the 2 tables like this:

```
select s.sid, s.sname, s.gpa, t.dname
from (
  select dname, max(s.gpa) maxgpa
  from major m inner join student s
  on s.sid = m.sid
  group by dname
  having count(s.sid) > 15
) t 
inner join major m on m.dname = t.dname
inner join student s on s.sid = m.sid and s.gpa = t.maxgpa
```

Or with window functions:

```
select t.sid, t.sname, t.gpa, t.dname
from (
  select m.dname, s.*,
    rank() over (partition by m.dname order by s.gpa desc) rn,
    count(s.sid) over (partition by m.dname) counter
  from major m inner join student s
  on s.sid = m.sid
) t
where t.counter > 15 and t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `WHERE ... IN` statement to be an `INNER JOIN`, you can connect more fields.

```
SELECT student.sid, student.sname, student.gpa, major.dname
FROM student 
RIGHT JOIN major 
  ON student.sid = major.sid 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  MAX(gpa) as max_gpa, dname
  FROM student JOIN major ON student.sid=major.sid
  GROUP BY dname
  HAVING COUNT(dname)>15
) as dept_gpa
  ON student.gpa = dept_gpa.max_gpa
    AND major.dname = dept_gpa.dname
```